# How to match a string with a regex only if it's between two delimiters?

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to delete all matches from an input using a regular expression with Java 7:

```java
input.replaceAll([regex], "");
```

Given this example `input` with a target string `abc-`:

```
<TAG>test-test-abc-abc-test-abc-test-</TAG>test-abc-test-abc-<TAG>test-abc-test-abc-abc-</TAG>
```

What regex could I use in the code above to match `abc-` **only** when it is between the `<TAG>` and `</TAG>` delimiters? Here is the desired matching behaviour, with `<-->` for a match:

```
               <--><-->     <-->                                       <-->     <--><-->
<TAG>test-test-abc-abc-test-abc-test-</TAG>test-abc-test-abc-<TAG>test-abc-test-abc-abc-</TAG>
```

Expected result:

```
<TAG>test-test-test-test-</TAG>test-abc-test-abc-<TAG>test-test-</TAG>
```

The left and right delimiters are always different. I am not particularly looking for a recursive solution (nested delimiters).

I think this might be doable with lookaheads and/or lookbehinds but I didn't get anywhere with them.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I edited my post to specify my end goal which is to remove all occurrences of a string using Java 7.

Comment: You're not gonna believe this but there exist XML/HTML parsers in Java which will let you achieve your goal more easily using XPath

Comment: It will be as simple as `//tag[text()[contains(.,'abc-')]]`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I wanted to use a parser (`jsoup`) at the beginning. However, without going into too much detail, I am working on a legacy Java application and I can't introduce a parser at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```java
(?s)(\G(?!^)|<TAG>(?=.*?</TAG>))((?:(?!<TAG>|</TAG>).)*?)abc-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ckBsvr/1). Replace with `$1$2`. *Details*:

- `(?s)` - a `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option
- `(\G(?!^)|<TAG>(?=.*?</TAG>))` - Group 1 (`$1`): either of the two:

  - `\G(?!^)` - end of the previous successful match
  - `|` - or
  - `<TAG>(?=.*?</TAG>)` - `<TAG>` that is immediately followed with any zero or more chars, as few as possible, followed with `</TAG>` (thus, we make sure there is actually the closing, right-hand delimiter further in the string)
- `((?:(?!<TAG>|</TAG>).)*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any one char (`.`), zero or more repetitions, but as few as possible (`*?`) that does not start a `<TAG>` or `</TAG>` char sequences (aka [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970))
- `abc-` - the pattern to be removed, `abc-`.

In Java:

```java
String pattern = "(?s)(\\G(?!^)|<TAG>(?=.*?</TAG>))((?:(?!<TAG>|</TAG>).)*?)abc-";
String result = text.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2");
```